# how to read a keyword in text file and the next lines till a blank line in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a keyword in a text file and read all lines following it until a blank line is found.

Please help.

This is what I tried.

```
import linecache

line_number = 0
file_name = 'jobs.txt'

with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
    for line in read_obj:
        line_number += 1
        if 'keyword' in line:

            # print(line_number,line.strip())
            for i in range(line_number,10,1):
                print(linecache.getline('jobs.txt',line_number+1))
```

expected output:

[[server1|web1],[server1|web2]]

### jobs.txt

```
keyword
server1|web1
server1|web2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the lines, validate the keyword has been found, check if the next line is empty, if not add the line as a list to the result list. If its blank, `break`.

```
res = []
file_name = 'jobs.txt'
found = False

with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
    for line in read_obj:
        if found: 
            if line is "\n": 
                break
            res.append([line.strip()])
        if 'client::CUSTOMIZED' in line:
            found = True

print(res)

OUT: [['server1|web1'], ['server1|web2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('jobs.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as read_obj:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in read_obj]

result = []
app = True

for line in lines:
    if line == 'keyword':  # or what you want! This is start line.
        app = True
    elif line == '':  # or what you want! This is end line.
        app = False

    if app:
        result.append(line)
        app = False
        break  # or continue
print(result)
```